# Htaccess internal redirect from domain to another url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, internal

Yet another .htaccess rewrite question... But can't find a way to make it work

My goal :

- **http://one.domain.com** -> **http://another.domain.com/specific/url**
- I'm not looking for a **redirect**, but a **rewrite**.
- one.domain.com is a vhost alias on another.domain.com vhost.
- No need for URL rest ($1...) it can be a perfect match (one-page site).

My best shot below makes a redirect, which I don't want.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^one\.domain\.com$     
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://another.domain.com/specific/url [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done using `RewriteRule` - from the [Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule):

> **Absolute URL**
>
> If an absolute URL is specified, mod_rewrite checks to see whether the hostname matches the current host. If it does, the scheme and
>   hostname are stripped out and the resulting path is treated as a
>   URL-path. **Otherwise, an external redirect is performed for the given
>   URL.**

You may want to use a workaround, e.g. reading the page `http://another.domain.com/specific/url` with Curl and then outputting the contents using `echo()` (if you're using PHP). Anyway it looks like a hard-to-maintain solution.